# Query Variable to get value from Cookie?

Tags: 2013, search

I've got a value stored in a cookie and I want to use it in the Query Text of a Result Source.

In the article [Query variables in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123(v=office.15).aspx) I don't see anything obvious to try.  It does mention you can use `{Request.<PropertyName>}` which is a value from the current http request - for example, {Request.Url}, but it doesn't say what else in the Request you can use.

Any information on what else is available in Request or any other ideas?

I'm using a cookie because I want to maintain this piece of information as the user browses the site.  This information will come from a dropdown selection the user can make in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but have you tried `{Request.Cookies("MyCookie")}`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  If I look at the Query Text in the TEST tab of the Build Your Query dialog, {Request.Url} actually gets replaced with the URL, however {Request.Cookies("MyCookie")} doesn't get replaced with the value in the cookie and remains as {Request.Cookies("MyCookie")}.  I tried {Request.Cookies["MyCookie"]} as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation sounds like the member will be resolved via Reflection, the acutal implementation simply calls [HttpRequest.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) Method which returns:

> The QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collection member specified in the key parameter. If the specified key is not found, then null is returned.

So you only need to have a unique cookie name that does not collide with the other sources. For example if you name your cookie "MyCookie" you can easily use a search query like:

Title:{Request.MyCookie}

I hope that helps somebody, even the question is old.